# G++-5 tr1/regex regex_replace could not be resolved

Tags: c++, regex, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I am using G++-5 with the dialect option `-std=c++0x` and the preprocessor symbol `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` and I am trying to use the `tr1/regex`.

I use `#include <tr1/regex>` with `using namespace std::tr1;` and `regex reg("<[^>]*>");` trows no error.
Only when I use `regex_replace(line, reg, "");` afterwards, I get the following error output:

```
Function 'regex_replace' could not be resolved  test.cpp    /cppUni/src line 72 Semantic Error

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
#0 regex_replace(#0, #1, #1, const std::tr1::basic_regex<#3,#2> &, const ? &, std::bitset<unsigned long int11>)
? regex_replace(const ? &, const std::tr1::basic_regex<#1,#0> &, const ? &, std::bitset<unsigned long int11>)
'   test.cpp    /cppUni/src line 72 Semantic Error
```

I verified, that `line` is a String.

I searched for a solution the last couple of hours and could only find solutions that involved what I attempted.
Unfortunately I can't use the `boost/regex` package.

Is there a solution for this issue?

EDIT:

```
#include <tr1/regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  std::tr1::regex reg("<[^>]*>");  
  string line = "<Day>22</Day>";

  if(line.find("<Day>") != string::npos)
    {
        line =std::tr1::regex_replace(line, reg, "");
        cout<<line<<endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

`g++-5 -std=c++11 -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -Wall test.cpp -o test.out`

Comment: You know, gcc5 is fairly C++11 compliant, you can just use `std::regex` from `<regex>` with `-std=c++11` and forget about that tr1 stuff.

Comment: Also, please [edit] this question to include a [mcve].

Comment: I tried that already, thats when even regex `reg("<[^>]*>");` couldn't be resolved

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/azfjDWqTeH63TM4e). MCVE please.

Comment: Alright, in tr1::regex you apparently need `std::tr1::regex_replace(line, reg, string(""));`. (Though that resulted in a linker error in Wandbox, but maybe they just don't have that legacy stuff installed, I dunno.) You should just use `std::regex` from C++11 instead, it works fine as I showed above.

Comment: That also solved it for me, thanks. I will change my project from std::tr1::regex to std::regex. Thanks again

Comment: You can actually self-answer your question. If you don't mind, would you please move the answer into a proper answer below? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have this answered:
User "Baum mit Augen" solved the issue by saying:

> Alright, in tr1::regex you apparently need std::tr1::regex_replace(line, reg, string(""));. (Though that resulted in a linker error in Wandbox, but maybe they just don't have that legacy stuff installed, I dunno.) You should just use std::regex from C++11 instead, it works fine as I showed above. – Baum mit Augen May 28 at 11:10